# Как открыть файл из ресурсов программы?

Tags: c#

Как из программы открыть этот файл test.txt ?
Например, при обработке нажатия на кнопку.
[image: Файлы ресурсов]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте свойство файла [image: Свойства файла]

Потом можно так :

```
   var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".Resources.test.txt";       
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();  
Console.Write(result);
        }
   Console.ReadLine();
```

Ноб есть еще вариант поменяйте свойства `Copy to Output Directory` на `Copy always` (не знаю как будет по-русски)

[image: Ствойтсва файла]

Потом можно просто

`StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("Resources\\test.txt");`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/luuhsi
Всё сделал, поменял свойство Build Action На нужно
Но файл не открывается. После запуска программа просто закрывается

Comment: @АндрейЛёвушкин, так и должно быть Если хочешь что - то вывести, используй Console.WriteLine потом Console.Readline чтобы не закрывалось окно. Смотри я изменил код

Comment: А если у нас исполняемый файл, и нужно его выполнить из ресурсов программы?

Comment: @АндрейЛёвушкин, Если вы имели ввиду выполнение команд через командную строку Windows (.bat, .exe файлы)  то в C# можно исполнять их без хранение каких то файлов. Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод [GetManifestResourceStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetManifestResourceStream_System_String_).

Например:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("имя_файла"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Ошибка:
http://prntscr.com/lutndd

Comment: @АндрейЛёвушкин у вас файл в подпапке, имя скорее всего будет `Resources.test.txt` и да, файл должен быть помечен как embeded в свойствах.

Comment: Не могу найти почему-то, где в свойствах файла пометить его как embeded